# Python / Dajngo App deployed using WSGI is getting stuck to generate the HTTP response

Tags: python, django, heroku, wsgi

I'm using Heroku to deploy my application, I'm using gunicorn.

For some requests, we're facing a really long time to generate the HTTP response, generated by the WSGI handler. The logs don't provide any insights and checking new relic I found this information:

[Transaction chart][1]
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vt0p.png
[Transaction breakdown][2]
    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1f98.png
[Transaction trace][3]
    [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJkKQ.png

Do you know what could be happening? or do you have any advice about how to approach these kinds of problems? thanks!

Comment: You could show the code of one of those views + template, otherwise it's a wild guess. Many times the issue is "following" the foreign-key relationship in a loop that creates hundreds of queries and can usually be fixed by using `select_related()` method.

Comment: @Borut the code is really big and the template too!

The issues are not reproducible in the local environment! so I guess if the issue was due to that reason it should be replicable in local env right :)? 

I'm trying to switch from gunicorn to uWSGI to see if I can fix the issue.

Comment: I'd start by installing Django Debug Toolbar. This could reveal an issue with the queries. Then run explain queries on the local and production database and compare them. Last thing I'd check is disk I/O and CPU performance.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue of moving from gunicorn to uWSGI deployment technology. all the issues got solved!